# LEDs with built-in resistors

Tags: led, resistors

Do they make LEDs that have a resistor built-in on the anode? If not, why not?

Comment: Yes, they make LEDs with built-in resistors. Since they're in series, it doesn't matter whether it's on the anode or the cathode.

Comment: @Kslkgh  Why do you want the resistor specifically on the anode side?  What difference does it make for you?

Comment: @NickAlexeev - I'm just used to connecting an LED with the resistor on the anode. I don't desperately want one, it's just how I'm used to connecting them.

Comment: @DaveTweed - Could you post me a link?

Comment: Such a thing did exsist, but I have seen this only once 15 years ago. I suspect that the power dissipation is a problem if you include a resistor in the same package, but I do not know which location would be best to place the built-in resistor. Maybe the silicon process dictates one location is better than the other. Sadly I do not know anything about silicon-level circuit design.

Comment: This would not be a good idea to produce. It would restrict the usage of the LED to one specific voltage. More interesting would be if the LED has an internal constant current source. Then the current is right for a bigger range of input voltage. But I have never seen something like that.

Comment: @Botnic - Good point. I hadn't thought of that (mainly because I generally work with strict 5V, or using a 7805 Linear Voltage Regulator to convert 7 - 30 volts into strict 5V).

Comment: @user65640: Google "led integrated resistor"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get them (I've just checked the Maplin Electronics web site).  They tend to be optimised for a few common voltages only, and then only for small indicator LEDS where the current draw is low.

For bigger LEDS intended as light sources, you're expected to provide a suitable regulated power supply.